# Zombie.js can't find button element on page

Tags: css, node.js, zombie.js

I'm trying to submit a form with zombie.js, and pressButton() is failing with "Error: No BUTTON 'xxx'", where xxx is the selector.  Here is the app:

```
var Browser = require('zombie');
b = new Browser();
b.visit('https://www.example.com/login/', function() {
        b.
          fill('name', 'My Name').
          fill('code', 'My Code').
          pressButton('submit', function() {
                console.log(b.html());
          });
});
```

And here is the form:

```
<form method="post" class="login">
    <p> <label for="name"> <span id="nameprompt">Your Name:</span> </label> </p>
        <input name="name" id="name" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" />
    <p> <label for="code"> <span id="codeprompt">Bar Code</span> </label> </p>
        <input name="code" id="code" type="PASSWORD" value="" size="40" maxlength="40" />
    <div class="formButtonArea">
        <input type="image" src="/screens/pat_submit.gif" border="0" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried a bunch of selectors including things like ".formButtonArea input" in addition to the obvious "submit" with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need the input to be of type="submit" (or type="button" perhaps). According to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zombie-js/8L0_Cpn8vVU, where the author comments on *clickLink*, it's likely that *clickButton* will do the same: find buttons and then fire *click*.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's worse than that, actually.  It seems that even the most basic of examples at the top of the Zombie docs doesn't work.  Consider this post where I describe it in detail:  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zombie-js/td1xsvxc8Es  All I got was dead air in response.  I'm afraid I may have to abandon the tool as it's just too fragile.  Shame, I really need it.

Comment: Oh, and to address the explicit issue in your reply, the site I'm scraping is not under my control, so I was somewhat stuck with the content.  However, I actually used the DOM to edit the input type to both submit and button.  Neither worked.

Comment: Links are not answers.

Comment: @Carlos Is there a way to click on an image with zombie?